# Why my table does not center?

Tags: xtable

For some reasons my table does not center which is odd since I am doing exactly the same with another table in the same tex file and it works. Could someone help me?

```
\documentclass[
10pt,
a4paper,
oneside,
headinclude,footinclude,
BCOR5mm,
]{scrartcl} 
\usepackage[scale=0.8]{geometry}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[hbt]
 \centering
  \caption{Indicators used by the ARWU and weight associated with each indicator}
    \begin{tabular}{lc} 
      \toprule
      \textbf{Indicators} & \textbf{Weight} \\
      \midrule
      Number of alumni & 10\% \\
      Staff winning Nobel Prizes and Fields Medals & 20\% \\
      Number of highly cited researchers selected by Thomson Reuters & 20\% \\
      Number of articles published in journals of Nature and Science & 20\% \\
      Number of articles indexed in SCI - ESSCI & 20\% \\
      Per capita performance & 10\% \\
      \bottomrule
     \end{tabular}
    \begin{tablenotes}
     \small
     \item Abbreviations: SCI, Science Citation Index; ESSCI, Expanded and Social Sciences Citation Index. \\
    \end{tablenotes}
 \label{tab:label}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

There are not `threeparttable` environment in your MWE.

[image: MWEE]

```
\documentclass[
10pt,
a4paper,
oneside,
headinclude,footinclude,
BCOR5mm,
]{scrartcl} 
\usepackage[scale=0.8]{geometry}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[hbt]
 \centering
\begin{threeparttable}  
  \caption{Indicators used by the ARWU and weight associated with each indicator}
    \begin{tabular}{lc} 
      \toprule
      \textbf{Indicators} & \textbf{Weight} \\
      \midrule
      Number of alumni & 10\% \\
      Staff winning Nobel Prizes and Fields Medals & 20\% \\
      Number of highly cited researchers selected by Thomson Reuters & 20\% \\
      Number of articles published in journals of Nature and Science & 20\% \\
      Number of articles indexed in SCI - ESSCI & 20\% \\
      Per capita performance & 10\% \\
      \bottomrule
     \end{tabular}
         \begin{tablenotes}
     \small
     \item Abbreviations: SCI, Science Citation Index; ESSCI, Expanded and Social Sciences Citation Index. \\
    \end{tablenotes}
 \end{threeparttable}  
 \label{tab:label}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Always useful to read [the documentation](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/threeparttable), I guess!

Answer (score 2):

Here, I put the `tablenotes` in a `\parbox` of limited width.

```
\documentclass[
10pt,
a4paper,
oneside,
headinclude,footinclude,
BCOR5mm,
]{scrartcl} 
\usepackage[scale=0.8]{geometry}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[hbt]
 \centering
  \caption{Indicators used by the ARWU and weight associated with each indicator}
    \begin{tabular}{lc} 
      \toprule
      \textbf{Indicators} & \textbf{Weight} \\
      \midrule
      Number of alumni & 10\% \\
      Staff winning Nobel Prizes and Fields Medals & 20\% \\
      Number of highly cited researchers selected by Thomson Reuters & 20\% \\
      Number of articles published in journals of Nature and Science & 20\% \\
      Number of articles indexed in SCI - ESSCI & 20\% \\
      Per capita performance & 10\% \\
      \bottomrule
     \end{tabular}\par
\parbox{4.5in}{
    \begin{tablenotes}
     \small
     \item Abbreviations: SCI, Science Citation Index; ESSCI, Expanded and Social Sciences Citation Index. \\
    \end{tablenotes}
}
 \label{tab:label}
\end{table}

\noindent\hrulefill
\end{document}
```

[image]